# Symfony2 - "Logging" but not "Authenticated"

Tags: php, symfony

I try to create a authentification without FOSUser.
But I have a problem. When I login, in the toolbar I'm not "Authenticate" :

[image: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/939138Capturedcran20150812095014.png]

I don't understand why.

User.php

```
<?php

namespace FermierMalin\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FermierMalin\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Ce compte existe déjà")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="L'adresse email est requise")
     * @Assert\Email(message="L'adresse email n'est pas valide")
     * @ORM\Column (type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le mot de passe est requis")
     * @Assert\Length(min=4, max=50, minMessage="Le mot de passe doit faire au moins {{ limit }} caractères", maxMessage="Le mot de passe doit faire moins de {{ limit }} caractères")
     * @ORM\Column (type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le prénom est requis")
     * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=50, minMessage="Le prénom doit faire au moins {{ limit }} caractères", maxMessage="Le prénom doit faire moins de {{ limit }} caractères")
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=50, minMessage="Le nom doit faire au moins {{ limit }} caractères", maxMessage="Le nom doit faire moins de {{ limit }} caractères")
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var \Datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \Datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updatedTimestamps()
    {
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));

        if ($this->getCreatedAt() == null) {
            $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     * @param string $serialized
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     *
     * @return Role[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->getEmail();
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Add roles
     *
     * @param Role $roles
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRole(Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove roles
     *
     * @param Role $roles
     */
    public function removeRole(Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
    }
}
```

Role.php

```
<?php

namespace FermierMalin\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_role")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @see RoleInterface
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param User $users
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addUser(User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove users
     *
     * @param User $users
     */
    public function removeUser(User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

Security.yml :

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FermierMalin\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: md5
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 0

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_GROWER: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_CONSUMER: ROLE_USER

    providers:
        main:
           entity: { class: FermierMalin\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: email}

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            provider: main

            form_login:
                login_path: /connexion
                check_path: /login_check
                username_parameter: _email

            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
```

My user have a role, so I don't understand this behavior!

Answer (score 0):

In your security.yml file, there is no Access control for logged users like below..

access_control:

```
    user_secured_pages:
        path: /user
        roles: [ROLE_USER]
```

Can you please try it by adding the corresponding role of the logging user ?

Comment: I try, But I have the same result. I don't secure some paths but some actions in my controllers. I would use "Secure" annotation. With your code, my user is not "Authenticate"...